# vim Different configuration in tty1-6 from tty7

Tags: vim, tty

The default configuration for vim seems to be different for tty7. When I open a terminal in the default gui on tty7 and start vim I can hold shift and press the left or right arrows to move the cursor by whole words. When I open tty1 and start vim I cannot hold shift and press the left and right arrow keys to move the cursors by whole words. Others differences include different colour scheme and different cursor type. My `.vimrc` file is just autoindent and number and does get loaded by both ttys. Is there another vim configuration file that the terminal application is loading or is there something else causing the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal emulator's colour palette might be different from that of the TTY's framebuffer. [How can I change the TTY colors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147462/how-can-i-change-the-tty-colors)

The same applies to cursor type, since that can be set by the terminal emulator. [How to change cursor shape, color, and blinkrate of Linux Console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55423/how-to-change-cursor-shape-color-and-blinkrate-of-linux-console) [How to stop cursor from blinking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-to-stop-cursor-from-blinking)

As for the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it is likely that the X window system interprets <kbd>Shift</kbd>+an arrow key as a different event compared to just an arrow key. The terminal emulators interpret whatever X sends them. The console terminal driver probably does not support modifiers like <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with the arrow keys.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. I was able to test the shift difference because Shift+Up/Down/Left/Right in the gui terminal outputs `ABCD` respectively whereas the text mode one does nothing.